# Don't know how to build task 'script/generate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I started learning ruby on rails today, and I always encounter some sort of error. I'm following the tutorial on tutorialspoint. Now when I ran `rails script/generate model Book` I encountered

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'script/generate' (see --tasks)
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Great! thanks for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drop the `script` part:

```
rails generate model Book # will work
```

P.S. Everyone starts with [Hartl's tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book), I think you should, too.